# Fastest (to implement) way to find pattern in an XML node

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML file which contains some Nodes that needs to be varied at runtime. For example:

```
<pt:Type>#type</pt:Type>
<pt:Value>#value</pt:Value>
```

I'd like to scan the XML file and search for Nodes which have a "#" pattern in it. My purpose is to fill up the XML using some data I have in memory. Which is the fastest way to do it in Java ? Maybe is there an XPath expression to gather all nodes having a certain value ?

Comment: With "fast", do you mean fast to implement or is it essential that the runtime performance is fast? You can surely use XPath to select nodes based on their text content, which is fast and easy to implement, but probably won't have optimal runtime performance.

Comment: what kind of information do you need to find ? a boolean (yes, my file contains a text node starting with #) a path from the root to the node, the name of the element  ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *XPath* query with the `contains` criteria function which would return elements that which values holds the set of character provided. It should be something like the following:

```
//*[contains(text(), '#')]
```

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to go with XQuery pattern matching in java way something like this

```
XQExpression xqe = xqc.createExpression();
xqe.executeQuery("doc('orders.xml')//order[id='174']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Xpath

Any node where the first text child node equals '#type':

`//*[text() =  '#type']`

Any node where the first text child node starts with '#':

`//*[starts-with(text(), '#')]`

Any node where the first text child node starts with '#' after normalizing spaces:

`//*[starts-with(normalize-space(text()), '#')]`